# Позиционирование элементов при помощи flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как разместить элементы так как показано на скрине.
Извините что без картинок пример кода, долго просто буду подгружать.

```css
.expertice{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    padding: 45px 215px 0 190px ;
    height: 900px;
}

.icons{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    
    min-width: 343px;
    height: 322px;
}
```

```html
<div class="expertice">
       <h2>EXPERTISE</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet proin gravida nibh vel velit</p>
        <div class="icons">
        <img src="img/TV.png" alt="">
        <h3>WEB DESIGN & DEVELOPMENT</h3>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
        <img src="img/pan.png" alt="">
        <h3>BRANDING IDENTITY</h3>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
        <img src="img/phone.png" alt="">
        <h3>MOBILE APP</h3>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
        <img src="img/diagram.png" alt="">
        <h3>SEARCH ENGINE OPTIMIZATION</h3>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
        <img src="img/tetris.png" alt="">
        <h3>GAME DEVELOPMENT</h3>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
        <img src="img/heart.png" alt="">
        <h3>MADE WITH LOVE</h3>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Добавил но не чего не изменилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне не понятна задача.. это то что надо ?

```css
i.fa {
  font-size: 4em;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.name {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.item h3 {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.item p {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 6px auto;
}

@media (max-width:700px) {
  .items {
    flex-direction: space-between;
  }
  .item {
    width: 40%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:540px) {
  .items {
    flex-direction: space-between;
  }
  .item {
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 280px;
  }
  .item p {
    width: 70%;
  }
  .name p {
    font-siize: 14px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: ;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="items">
  <div class="name">
    <h3>expertise</h3>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-television"></i>
    <h3>web design & development</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, temporibus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
    <h3>BRANDING IDENTITY</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, temporibus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>
    <h3>SEARCH ENGINE OPTIMIZATION</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, temporibus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
    <h3>GAME DEVELOPMENT</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, temporibus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
    <h3>MADE WITH LOVE</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, temporibus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-tablet"></i>
    <h3>mobile app</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, temporibus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вау просто я ещё не до конца в флекс боксах разбираюсь спасибо.